# filesystem url of a svn repository

Tags: svn, rally

I am trying to integrate Rally with Subversion.
All 3 ie, Rally, Subversion and the SubversionConnectorforRally are on different remote servers. Now how do I put the filesystem url of a svn repository which is on a remote windows machine ?  it should be something of the form file:/// which is what the repository.yml file of SubversionConnectorforRally expects.

Comment: *Don't* use `file://` URLs in subversion. Use `svn://` or any other protocol.

Answer (score 0):

```
.....
Subversion:
    Server              : vm-ubuntu-64.acme.com
    RepositoryBase      : /var/subversion/Demo-centralized-master-repo
.....
```

Linux example:
    https://help.rallydev.com/how-to-install-and-use-the-svn-connector-on-linux